# Solutions of a system with parameter $a$ and three unknown $x,y,z$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

Recently, I found this problem:

> Find all integer solutions of $x,y,z$ of the following system:
>   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 5x + (a + 2)y + (a + 2)z = a
> \\(2a+4)x+(a^2+3)y+(2a+2)z=3a-1
> \\ (2a + 4)x + (2a + 2)y + (a^2 + 3)z = a + 1
> \end{matrix}\right.
> $$

where $a\in Z$

I don't know about matrix calculations, so I would like to find the solutions with, for example, substitution or sum-difference method.

For example I have tried subtracting the third equation from the second, getting: $(a-1)^2(y-z)=2(a-1)$ but here I'm stuck.

Comment: I'd recommend you to learn matrix calculations. It's not so hard and will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

That is such an awesome start. Now Either $a=1$ or not. If so, then the equations reduce to$$5x+3y+3z=1\\3x+2y+2z=1$$which is very easy to solve.

The case $a\ne 1$ is more interesting, for which$$(a-1)^2(y-z)=2(a-1)\implies (a-1)(y-z)=2$$therefore we have an answer only if $$a-1|2\to a\in\{-1,0,2,3\}$$under which we have $$y-z={2\over a-1}$$which gives us the answer by substitution.